# Factory pattern with unique_ptr

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, factory-pattern

I have abstract class Agent, and few derived: Predator, Prey etc. I would like to make a factory, that gives me unique_ptr which I can store in vector of base class.

Problem is, when I have:

```
using creatorFunctionType = std::unique_ptr<Agent>(*)();
```

this part is ok, but in map I cannot use lambda with:

```
return std::make_unique<Predator>();
```

But when I am trying to use template:

```
template <class T>
using creatorFunctionType = std::unique_ptr<T>(*)();
```

The rest of functions doesn't compile. I am nearby sure, I missed something important about templates, but no idea what. Can you give me some hints?

Posting full code, may be helpful

AgentFactory.h

```
#include "Interfaces/Agent.h"
#include "Enums.h"
#include <map>
#include <memory>

class AgentFactory
{
public:
    template <class T>
    using creatorFunctionType = std::unique_ptr<T>(*)();

    AgentFactory();
    std::unique_ptr<Agent> createAgent(Enums::AgentType agentType);
private:
    void registerAgentType(Enums::AgentType agentType, creatorFunctionType 
    creatorFunction);

    std::map<Enums::AgentType, creatorFunctionType> factoryRegister;
};
```

AgentFactory.cpp

```
#include "AgentFactory.h"
#include "Predator.h"
#include "Prey.h"

AgentFactory::AgentFactory()
{
    registerAgentType(Enums::AgentType::Predator, []() { return         
    std::make_unique<Predator>(); });
    registerAgentType(Enums::AgentType::Prey, []() { return     
    std::make_unique<Prey>(); });
}

std::unique_ptr<Agent> AgentFactory::createAgent(Enums::AgentType 
agentType)
{
    if (auto it = factoryRegister.find(agentType); it != 
    factoryRegister.end()) {
        return it->second();
    }

    return nullptr;
}

void AgentFactory::registerAgentType(Enums::AgentType agentType, 
creatorFunctionType creatorFunction)
{
    factoryRegister.insert(std::pair<Enums::AgentType, 
    creatorFunctionType>(agentType, creatorFunction));
}
```

Compilation errors:

```
1>d:\predator-prey\predator-prey\agentfactory.h(15): error C2955: 'AgentFactory::creatorFunctionType': use of alias template requires template argument list
1>d:\predator-prey\predator-prey\agentfactory.h(10): note: see declaration of 'AgentFactory::creatorFunctionType'
1>d:\predator-prey\predator-prey\agentfactory.h(17): error C3203: 'creatorFunctionType': unspecialized alias template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter '_Ty', expected a real type
1>d:\predator-prey\predator-prey\agentfactory.cpp(14): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments
1>d:\predator-prey\predator-prey\agentfactory.cpp(22): error C3203: 'creatorFunctionType': unspecialized alias template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter '_Ty2', expected a real type
1>d:\predator-prey\predator-prey\agentfactory.cpp(22): fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation
```

Comment: Where is your move ctor/assignment for Agent?

Comment: @user10933809 what does that have to do with anything? That is irrelevant to this question

Comment: @MichaelS you say the code does not compile, what are the actual errors? When using `using creatorFunctionType = std::unique_ptr<Agent>(*)();`, try giving the lambdas an explicit return type: `[]() -> std::unique_ptr<Agent> { return std::make_unique<Predator>(); }` A `unique_ptr<Predator>` is implicitly convertible to `unique_ptr<Agent>` as long as `Predator` derives from `Agent`

Comment: Agent has only constructor Agent(int ID_). There is no move nor assignment. Are they necessary?

Comment: @MichaelS. for purposes of this question, no they are not. How you construct your objects is irrelevent, what you are asking for is how to assign the function pointers correctly, and that has nothing to do with object construction.

Comment: please try to provide a [mcve] and include the full error message in the question. One would have to add some missing pieces to the code you posted to get anywhere near to the error you get

Comment: @RemyLebeau, added compilation errors in question

Comment: @MichaelS. OK, but those errors apply to `template <class T>
using creatorFunctionType = std::unique_ptr<T>(*)();` What happens when you go back to `using creatorFunctionType = std::unique_ptr<Agent>(*)();` instead? Did you try the suggestion I offered?

Comment: @RemyLebeau, when added []() -> std::unique_ptr<Agent> to lambda and do not use template, everything seems to work ok

Comment: @MichaelS. OK, I added an answer about that now.

Comment: The original problem is that `template<T> using creatorFunctionType = std::unique_ptr<T>(*)();` declares `creatorFunctionType` as a template type. It is not yet a type. To make it a type, you need to instantiate the template by saying `creatorFunctionType<Agent>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `creatorFunctionType` is defined as

```
using creatorFunctionType = std::unique_ptr<Agent>(*)();
```

`creatorFunctionType` is a pointer-to-function that expects functions which return a `std::unique_ptr<Agent>`.

However, your lambdas do not have explicit return types, so the compiler deduces their return types as `std::unique_ptr<Predator>` and `std::unique_ptr<Prey>`, respectively, based on their `return` statements.

A non-capturing lambda is implicitly convertible to a pointer-to-function, which is what you want in this case, however your lambdas do not return `std::unique_ptr<Agent>`, so they cannot be assigned to `creatorFunctionType`.  The types simply do not match.

You need to be explicit about the return type of your lambdas so they match the correct signature that `creatorFunctionType` is expecting, eg:

```
AgentFactory::AgentFactory()
{
    registerAgentType(Enums::AgentType::Predator,
        []() -> std::unique_ptr<Agent> { return std::make_unique<Predator>(); }
    );
    registerAgentType(Enums::AgentType::Prey,
        []() -> std::unique_ptr<Agent> { return std::make_unique<Prey>(); }
    );
}
```

With the above code, the lambdas will now return `std::unique_ptr<Agent>`, satisfying what `creatorFunctionType` expects.  And the `return` statements still work as-is because `std::unique_ptr<T>` can be initialized with a `std::unique_ptr<U>` as long as `U` derives from `T`, which is true in your case since `Predator` and `Prey` derive from `Agent`.